# Forwarding Rdp packets using netsh tool

Tags: windows, networking, ip-address, portforwarding, netsh

I’m trying to create rdp connection from my computer (A) to another (B) but I want to use a different source ip ( of computer C), I want to use C as a proxy between A and B, but I want to configure C remotely (I’m admin at both A and C), I’ve tried do this with Netsh portproxy I saw some examples but I can’t really figure how the rules should look.

To be clear I want to rdp from A to B but the request should have the source IP of C, and the response need to go back to A .

Thank you! 
Windows ops on all computers

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could resolve this situation using RRAS, more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd469812(v=ws.11))

However, you should consider using a linux box with iptables it's more versatile and have lots of capabilities.

Hope that helps!

Note: also take a look at this both links [NetNat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netnat/?view=win10-ps) [WinNat](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2016/05/25/windows-nat-winnat-capabilities-and-limitations/)

Regards